# How do you have multiple startup projects in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Looking through the [achievement list](http://channel9.msdn.com/achievements/visualstudio) for Visual Studio 2010, it says that there is an achievement for having [3 startup projects](http://channel9.msdn.com/achievements/visualstudio/MoreThan2StartupProjects).

How do you have multiple startup projects at once? Whenever I right click a project and select "Set as StartUp Project" it switches my current startup project to the new one. I wasn't aware multiple startup projects was even a possibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[How to: Set Multiple Startup Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx)**:

Visual Studio allows you to specify how more than one project is run when you start the debugger.

**To set multiple startup projects**

1. In Solution Explorer, select the solution.
2. On the **Project** menu, click **Properties**. The [Solution Property Pages Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x2s9w9f.aspx) opens.
3. Expand the **Common Properties** node, and click **Startup Project**.
4. Click **Multiple Startup Projects** and set the project actions. For more information, see [Startup Project, Common Properties, Solution Property Pages Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09138bex.aspx).